# How to plot frequencies of discrete categories?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Hi I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Seq     H   E   T   C
1   Seq_1   2   1   5   4
2   Seq_2   2   1   5   4
3   Seq_3   2   1   5   4
4   Seq_4   0   0   6   6
5   Seq_5   0   4   2   6
```

Where H,E,T and C represent the counts of these features within each sequence.

I'm trying to build a line graph where each line should represent one sequence. The X-axis will be the features (H,E,T,C) and the Y-axis its corresponding count, so the lines will show the count's variation within each sequence.

How should I do that? I've already messed around with a lot of things but couldn't make it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to ggplot is that it expects data to be in "long" format. It's often easiest to get it in this format with `melt`. Once melted, it becomes an exercise of specifying the plot as you want to view it. Here's an example:

```
txt <- "    Seq     H   E   T   C
1   Seq_1   2   1   5   4
2   Seq_2   2   1   5   4
3   Seq_3   2   1   5   4
4   Seq_4   0   0   6   6
5   Seq_5   0   4   2   6 "

dat <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

dat.m <- melt(dat)


ggplot(dat.m, aes(variable, value, group = Seq, colour = Seq)) + 
  geom_line()
```

This results in some overplotting issues for Seq_1 - Seq_3 so you may want to consider dropping colour and faceting instead:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(variable, value, group = Seq)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~Seq)
```

Faceting obviously becomes less useful when you have 100s of sequences to review.

[image]

Comment: Man! I had already done almost everything you said, but what did the trick was addind `group=Seq` to the `aes` function.

Now it worked like a charm, thanks a lot!!

The overplotting is not an issue for me, and faceting is not possible because I have more than 100 sequences.

Thanks again!